# Invoke Findbugs in Android Buck Build

Tags: android, findbugs, buck

I'm migrating my android project to build with Buck (from Gradle). What's the recommended way to run Findbugs in a Buck build? I couldn't find examples online for how to set that up.

Comment: 1. Why migrate to Buck? You should use their examples. 2. You should post this question on their github. Ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this plugin that allows you to use Buck build system in a Gradle project: https://github.com/uber/okbuck.